# Queries regarding DNS Server

Tags: dns-hosting

I want to configure DNS server in 172.16.81.6. After the complete installation and configuration of DNS server, I want all my users to browse the internet by giving DNS IP 172.16.81.6 in their systems. Without giving the DNS IP 172.16.81.6 in their system, the users should not be able to browse the internet.

For this, should I need to map 172.16.81.6 with the DNS IP given by ISP or just configuring DNS server in 172.16.81.6 will work?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough and I can actually find many points.

If you want to configure the machines in your network to use specific DNS server, this can be done easily if you are already using a DHCP server.

If you want to allow specific DNS server and deny other DNS servers, this can be done using network firewall.

You can configure your DNS server to use the ISP DNS server as forwarder. Otherwise, your DNS server should be allowed by the ISP to perform DNS lookups directly to Internet.